# Does a proof by contradiction always exist?

Tags: logic, provability

Good day,

Usually, proofs by contradictions are the easier, and sometimes, even the only ones available. However, there are cases where the easiest proof is not the proof by contradiction. For example, the one below:

From the definition of the rational numbers, all of them can be expressed as quotients of two integers. And from this, logically all rationals quotients as well, because:

$$
\forall a\ \forall b\ \forall c\ \forall d:\{a;b;c;d\}\subset\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\\
\left\{\frac a b;\frac c d\right\}\subset\mathbb Q;\ 
\frac{\ \frac a b\ }{\ \frac c d\ }=
\frac{\frac a b\times bd}{\frac c d\times bd}=
\frac{ad}{bc}\in \mathbb Q
$$

or more generally (and that in fact makes the proof almost superfluous as division is a multiplication and multiplication is commutative) for $m$ fractions:

$$
\forall a\ \forall b:\{a;b\}\subset\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\\
\bigcup_ {n=1}^m\left\{\frac {a_n} {b_n}\right\}\subset\mathbb Q;\ 
\prod_{n=1}^m \frac {a_n} {b_n}=
\frac {\prod_{n=1}^m a_n} {\prod_{n=1}^m b_n}
\in \mathbb Q
$$
(end example)

When I say proof by contradiction, I mean the false statement you assume in order to cause the contradiction must be fundamental to the proof, in such a way that if you remove it, there is no proof. Can such a proof always be found for any proven theorem/conjecture/formula?

Comment: What for? (Just curious...)

Comment: Shouldn't those R's be Q's?

Comment: @Did, exactly, I'm just curious. `:)` Because usually, one has a proof by contradiction, and gets the other one (generally more difficultly) afterwords. This case is different.

Comment: Yes, here a proof by contradiction is just a bad idea.

Comment: @Did, why? Are you saying not every proof can be made by contradiction? That gives me an idea to generalize the question. Wait a few minutes...

Comment: it can be made by contradiction trivially, but its not very interesting... namely one can just say suppose its not in $\mathbb{Q}$ do your proof and arrive at a contradiction

Comment: @DevenWare, that wouldn't really be a proof by contradiction, would it?

Comment: @DanielRust, I'm sorry, should I delete the question and repost it? (seriously, I don't mind) Besides, the original is still there, as an example. If you totally change the meaning of your answer as well no one will notice.

Comment: @JMCF125 No I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @Can you post another one eventually? (if you want to, of course)

Comment: @JMCF125 the new question is more difficult as it pertains to *all* theorems and so is probably best tackled by a logician.

Comment: @Daniel, well, at least all **proven** theorems. Otherwise it would be practically impossible! `:)` I'll add the logic tag.

Comment: With respect to the close votes claiming that this question is unclear: I disagree. It is perfectly clear. It is simply "Can every proven theorem be proven using contradiction?"

Comment: @user1729, I actually understand the first close vote, which is from when the question was quite different; but indeed the second has no clear reason of being. Ironic that the close vote for unclear is more unclear than the question...

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the edit. That does explain the first one.

Comment: @JMCF125 (replying to your response to me) No I believe that would really be a proof by contradiction. However, I do agree that it would be silly to phrase the proof in that way. It shows how you can convert an argument to an argument by contradiction if you really wanted to though

Answer (score 9):

Whenever something is provable *at all*, it is possible to disguise that proof as one by contradiction. But the result is not necessarily very enlightening.

Suppose we have some kind of valid argument for the proposition $P$. We can then also prove $P$ by contradiction:

> $P$ is true. Namely, assume for a contradiction that $\neg P$. Then *(insert the existing argument here)* and therefore $P$. But then both $\neg P$ (by assumption) and $P$ (by the argument we just gave), and that is a contradiction. Therefore $P$ is true, Q.E.D.

You may then object that the assumption $\neg P$ was not really used to produce the contradiction. Usual mathematical logic doesn't care about that, it allows assumptions to go unused without affecting the validity of a conclusion. But there are things called **relevance logics** that try to capture the idea that it is somehow wrong not to make any use of an assumption.

Unfortunately that doesn't help us here -- even according to relevance logic, the $\neg P$ assumption certainly *was* used to produce the contradiction in the above proof. Without it there wouldn't have been any contradiction at all, and the proof would fall apart.

---

It is a much more interesting question whether there are things that can **only** be proved by contradiction. Arguments that never use proof by contradiction are studied in **intuitionistic logic**, and it turns out that there are statements whose proofs depend essentially on intermediate steps by contradiction. For example, *Peirce's law*:
$$ ((P\Rightarrow Q)\Rightarrow P)\Rightarrow P $$
cannot be proved without admitting proof by contradiction, or something that is essentially equivalent to it.

Comment: Ahah! I knew someone would point that out (in fact, it was in a deleted answer, just not so formalized). Read more carefully my last paragraph: that's cheating. Saying $\lnot P$ must be essential for the whole thing to be a proof: in the case you suggested, it wouldn't be like so.

Comment: @JMCF125: I'm inviting you to attempt to _formalize_ the rule that's broken here to make it "cheating", then.

Comment: "For example, Peirce's law: ((P⇒Q)⇒P)⇒P cannot be proved without admitting proof by contradiction, or something that is essentially equivalent to it."  The only deduction rule other than uniform substitution of the following system is modus ponens.  The axioms are 1. Cpp  and 2. CCppCCCpqpp.  Now since CCppCCCpqpp is a thesis and so is Cpp, it follows that we can detach CCCpqpp.  Do you claim that CCppCCCpqpp is equivalent to proof by contradiction?

Comment: It's not clear what comes as meant by a proof here.  But, you can certainly demonstrate |=CCCpqpp in two-valued logic or Bochvar three-valued logic *without* any appeal to proof by contradiction.  The relevant proof tables take up a single page.  Additionally, *if* you can prove semantical completeness "if |=$\alpha$, then |-$\alpha$" for some logical system with a semantics and a derivation system where |=CCCpqpp *without* using proof by contradiction, then you metalogically argue that |-CCCpqpp. In other words CCCpqpp could get proved in the mathematical sense without proof by contradiction.

Comment: Additionally, "proof by contradiction" qualifies as a *rule of inference*.  It is not a logical axiom.  Rules of inference are NOT essentially equivalent to logical axioms.  You can prove CCCpqpp say from {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CpCqKpq, CCNpKqNqp} under uniform substitution and detachment.  At *no point* will you actually infer a contradiction if you do so, nor can you infer a contradiction from those axioms and those rules.

Comment: «It is a much more interesting question whether there are things that can only be proved by contradiction.»: but you already answered that! `:D` I'll still try to formalize disallowing the cheating ASAP.

Comment: May you take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575221/can-peirces-law-be-prooved-without-contradiction)?; it contradicts the last part of this answer (or maybe it doesn't, and I don't know it yet `:)`).

Answer (score 1):

There are many directions a proof can take.

Some proofs start with the conclusion, and each new step is a reverse implication until you reach "true".

Some proofs start with the assumptions (or "true"), and each new step is an implication until you reach the conclusion.

A proof by contradiction starts with the negation of the assumption, and each new step is an implication until you reach "false".  Logically speaking, you can *always* convert a proof by contradiction into a direction proof of the first type using demorgan's transforms.

Proof by contradiction:
$$ \lnot conclusion \rightarrow false $$
is equivalent to to
$$ conclusion \leftarrow true $$
and any intermediate steps
$$ a \rightarrow b$$
may be converted to
$$ \lnot a \leftarrow \lnot b $$

...unless of course, you are working with a very limited set of rules of inferences that don't admit both type of proofs.

Comment: It seems the OP aim be more complicated than something you've just said.

Comment: @I'mtoo, indeed. Although I didn't know that explicitly, I did know _modus tollens_, and the rest of what you said doesn't really answer the question (although it may be a base to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Any proof by contradiction in a consistent propositional calculus requires that a premise get discharged.  Consequently, that premise does not belong to the axiom/theorem set of that propositional calculus.  Discharging of premises for a propositional calculus *requires that you have a deduction metatheorem around*.  However, if you have no deduction metatheorem around, then proof by contradiction becomes *illegal* for that propositional calculus.

Suppose we have the following formation rules for well-formed formulas (wffs) following a [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) scheme.

1. All lower case letters of the Latin alphabet qualifies as a wff.
2. If $\alpha$ qualifies as a wff, then N$\alpha$ qualifies as a wff.
3. If $\alpha$ qualifies as a wff, and so does $\beta$ then C$\alpha$$\beta$ qualifies as a wff.

Suppose our only axiom is

1 CCpqCCqrCpr.

And we have the rule of detachment "From $\vdash$C$\alpha$$\beta$, as well as $\vdash$$\alpha$, we may infer $\vdash$$\beta$" and the rule of uniform substitution.  Such a system does qualify as consistent in that it is never the case that we have $\vdash$ $\alpha$ and $\vdash$ N$\alpha$.

We can prove

2 CCCCqrCprsCCpqs.

and

3 CCpCqrCCsqCpCsr.

Additionally, since every theorem of this system comes as a conditional, there exists no last theorem to this system.  However, neither the above theorems nor any other theorems of this system can get proven by contradiction according to the relevant definition of a proof for this system (something like every theorem is either the axiom CCpqCCqrCpr or can deduced in a finite sequence of well-formed formulas which starts with CCpqCCqrCpr, and uses only uniform substitution and detachment and ends with the theorem).

So, most definitely, NO, proof by contradiction doesn't always exist.

Comment: Would I ask you to tell us more about your notation, I can not follow your reasoning.
In addition, what's the reasoning for "First order" case?

Comment: @I'mtoo Once you have the formation rules for a predicate calculus, you can just add in an axiom which involves a quantifier.  A first-order logic doesn't change anything here, if you don't have the ability to make a proof by contradiction in the propositional calculus at hand.

Comment: Indeed I think you need to explain it better, or point to links explaining the notation ("why are there so many letters following each other?" comes to mind) and the reasoning. Also, what is a "wff"?

Comment: @I'mtoo Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @JMCF125 Thanks for the feedback.