# A question about Implicational Propositional Calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

My question is motivated by a previous post about [Implicational calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669305/deduction-theorem-modus-ponens-what-implicational-propositional-calculus)

Having showed that Mendelson (A1) and (A2) axioms plus *Peirce's law* are a complete axiom set for *implicational* fragment of propositional calculus, where :

> **(A1)**  $\mathcal{B} \rightarrow ( \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B})$
>
> **(A2)**  $(\mathcal{B} \rightarrow ( \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D})) \rightarrow ((\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}))$

and *Peirce's law* is :

> $((\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$

I'm not able to derive (A3), where :

**(A3)**  $(\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \lnot \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow ((\lnot \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C})$.

In order to extend *implicational calculus* to full *propositional calculus* I assume that we need to introduce $\bot$, in order to define $\lnot \mathcal{A}$ as $\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \bot$.

But I'm still unable to find the solution.

Comment: You are also allowed to conclude $Q$ from $P\to Q$ and $P$, aren't you?

Comment: Yes of course - having (A1) and (A2), they are enough for proving the *Deduction Theorem* (see Mendelson).

Comment: I think you will even need to introduce $ \bot \to A $ (ex falso quidlibet) as axiom , I am a bit puzzeling with it

Comment: @Willemien - I think you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I sorted out the outline, I still need to fill in the gaps but here something to start with:
(f = $ \bot $)

```
1  |- ( A -> (B->C)) -> ((A -> B)-> (A->C)))                 A2 
2  |- ( A -> (B->f)) -> ((A -> B)-> (A->f)))                 1 C := f
3  |- ( (A->f) -> (B->f) )-> (((A->f) -> B)-> ((A->f)->f)))  2 A := (A->f)
4  |- ((A -> B) -> A) -> A                                   A3 Peirce
5  |- ((A->f) -> A) -> A                                     4  B := f 
6  |- ((A->f) -> f) -> ((A->f) -> f)                         theorem (A -> A)
7  |- f -> A                                                 axiom 
8  |- ((A -> f) -> f) -> ((A -> f) -> A)                     hyp syll 6,7 
9  |- ((A -> f) -> f) -> A                                   hyp syll 8,5
10 |- ((A -> f) -> (B-> f)) -> (((A ->f) -> B)-> A )         hyp syll 3,9
```

And 10 is $  ( \lnot A  \to \lnot B) \to (( \lnot A  \to B) \to A ) $

good exercise

Comment: I agree : it works. Your *hyp syll* is my *Trans* and your (9) is *DN*.

Comment: The three axioms (A1), (A2) an *Peirce* are known (see Wikipedia) as Bernays–Tarski axiom system for *Implicational propositional calculus* (see Tarski's article of 1930 reprinted in Alfred Tarski, *Logic, Semantics, Metamathematics* (1956)). The addition of $\bot$ gives *classical logic* : with *hyp syll* in place of (A2) and $\bot \rightarrow A$ we have the Tarski-Bernays-Wajsberg axiom system, and with (A1), (A2) and *Double Negation* (i.e.$((A \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow \bot) \rightarrow A$) we have Church's axiom system.

Comment: The "hyp syll" rule used in step 8 is NOT the same "hyp syll" rule that gets used in step 9 (though both rules are valid).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is motivated by Alonzo Church, *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* (1956), Ex 12.7 [page 86].

We need $\bot$ and $\rightarrow$ as primitives and the definition of $\lnot A$ as : $A \rightarrow \bot$.

We need also as additional axiom, *Ex Falso Quodlibet* [see Church, para.$122, page 84] :

> $\vdash \bot \rightarrow A$.

With *EFQ* and *Peirce's law*, we can have *Double Negation* :

> $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \rightarrow A$.

*Proof*

1) $\lnot \lnot A$ --- assumed

2) $\lnot A \rightarrow \bot$ --- by def of $\lnot$

3) $\lnot A$ --- assumed

4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3) by *modus ponens*

5) $\vdash \bot \rightarrow A$ --- *EFQ*

6) $A$ --- from 4) and 5) by *mp*

7) $\lnot A \rightarrow A$ --- from 3) and 6) by *Deduction Theorem*

8) $\vdash (\lnot A \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A$ --- from *Peirce's law*

9) $A$ --- from 7) and 8) by *mp*

> 10) $\vdash \lnot \lnot A \rightarrow A$ --- from 1) and 9) by *DT*.

---

*Note*

See Joel W. Robbin, [Mathematical Logic : A First Course](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048645018X) (1969 - Dover reprint), page 22 : axiom schema (A3) of Mendelson's system can be replaced by : $\vdash (\lnot A \rightarrow \lnot B) \rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ or equivalently by  $\vdash (\lnot A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (\lnot B \rightarrow A)$.

Or we can replace it with *EFQ* and *Peirce's law*.

---

Now for the proof of Mendelson's **(A3)** :

1) $\lnot C \rightarrow \lnot B$ --- assumed

2) $\lnot C \rightarrow B$ --- assumed

3) $\lnot C$ --- assumed

4) $\lnot B$ --- from 1) and 3) by *modus ponens*

5) $B$ --- from 2) and 3) by *modus ponens*

6) $\bot$ --- from 4) and 5) and definition of $\lnot$, by *mp*

7) $\lnot \lnot C$ --- from 3) and 6) by *DT*

8) $C$ --- from 7) and *Double Negation*, by *mp*.

Finally, apply *Deduction Theorem* twice :

> > $\vdash (\lnot C \rightarrow \lnot B) \rightarrow ((\lnot C \rightarrow B) \rightarrow C)$.

---

We have used the *Deduction Theorem*, which is provable with **(A1)** and **(A2)** only.

Comment: just ahead of me, but i do it axiomatic, was wondering can you do itwithout EFQ but with $ (A \to B) \to (\lnot B \to \lnot A) $ ?

Comment: about $\neg\neg A\vdash  A$ why in $(3)$ (your first list) assume $\neg A$?. I do as so: assume $(A\to \bot)\to \bot$ and $\bot\to A$ by transitivity:  $(A\to \bot)\to A$, by Peirce: $((A\to \bot)\to A)\to A$, by MP follow $A$. By deduciton $\vdash \neg\neg A\to A$

Answer (score 1):

Combining the subformula strategy, weighting of the axioms and the goal, and a (partial) level saturation search, I've found a 15 step (excluding the axioms), level 5 proof using OTTER [1].  Actually, instead of proving

CCCp0Cq0CCCp0qp.  OTTER proved the more general

CCCpqCr0CCCpqrp. (we can substitute q/0, r/q in CCCpqCr0CCCpqrp to get CCCp0Cq0CCCp0qp, but we can't obtain CCCpqCr0CCCpqrp from CCCp0Cq0CCCp0qp by substitution alone).

Note that this does not imply that

CCNpNqCCNpqp could get replaced by

CCCpqNrCCCpqrp *without* the definition Np := Cp0.

Here's the proof:

```
axiom         3 CxCyx.                   Level of formula is 0.

axiom         4 CCxCyzCCxyCxz.           0

axiom         5 CCCxyxx.                 0

axiom         6 C0x.                     0

D3.3          7 CxCyCzy.                 1

D4.4          8 CCCxCyzCxyCCxCyzCxz.     1

D3.4          9 CxCCyCzuCCyzCyu.         1

D3.5         11 CxCCCyzyy.               1

D3.6         13 CxC0y.                   1

DD4.4.7      17 CCxCCyxzCxz.             2

D3.9         20 CxCyCCzCuvCCzuCzv.       2

D4.11        25 CCxCCyzyCxy.             2

D4.13        27 CCx0Cxy.                 2

D17.9        42 CCxyCCzxCzy.             3

DD4.4.20     51 CCxCCCyCzuCCyzCyuvCxv.   3

DD4.11.27    71 CCCxy0x.                 3

D51.42      224 CCCCxyCxzuCCxCyzu.       4

D42.71      300 CCxCCyz0Cxy.             4

D224.300   2474 CCCxyCz0CCCxyzx.         5
```

[1]- W. McCune, "OTTER and Mace2", http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/AR/otter/, 1988-2014.